# Error/Success message parsed between Struts and Spring or Spring and Struts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, struts2

I have an issue where the same success/error message is parsed between a struts managed jsp and a Spring managed jsp such that both pages display the same success/error message. For example

1. A Customer makes a selection on a struts managed jsp (page 1)
2. On submit the application goes to a Spring managed page (page 2)
3. The customer fills in other details on page 2 and clicks submit
4. The application redirects back to the struts managed page (page 1) and displays a success message.
5. The customer selects something else on page 1 and gets redirected back to page 2 and the same success message that was shown on page 1 is displayed again on page 2.

It seems that this can happen with struts to Spring and Spring to struts.
Im looking for a lead on how this might be happening and what strategy could be employed to manage this?

Comment: Can you include details with code, which demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I have the understanding that Struts 1.3 uses ActionMessages for displaying messages and errors however Spring doesnt have this feature.
Also I was told that addError() adds a session attribute that is supposed to be destroyed by Struts after its been called. However when the user navigates back to the Spring managed page the org.apache.struts.action.ACTION_MESSAGE key is still in the session and therefore the same message is displayed a second time. Im wondering what can be done to ensure Struts removes the key and value when the request is coming from Spring?

Comment: Continued.......From Spring we try to use the Struts ActionMessage concept in a Spring Controller i.e.
controller calls
```addMessage(getRequest(), "theKey", "meetingCode", text);```
ErrorHandlerController.class
```ErrorHandlerController { ....
ActionMessages requestMessages = (ActionMessages) request.getAttribute(Globals.MESSAGE_KEY);
requestMessages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(messageKey, arguments));
request.setAttribute(Globals.MESSAGE_KEY, requestMessages);
```....